# Extra reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, up-votes, score

Why have I got +16 reputation on this question when clearly it only has received 2 up votes.

[Why does it make sense to describe complex numbers through powers of $e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082455/why-does-it-make-sense-to-describe-complex-numbers-through-powers-of-e)

Not that I'm complaining.

Comment: 5 upvotes (25 rep) - 2 downvotes (4 rep) = 3 net votes (21 rep). For future reference: look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) when doing any accounting.

Answer (score 7):

Currently, the question has 6 upvotes and 2 downvotes, which gives score 4 and net reputation gain $6\cdot5-2\cdot2=26$.

You can view upvotes and downvotes on your [reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation).

If you sort it [by post](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/400808/triplea?tab=reputation&sort=post) you get this:

[image: reputation tab]

If you sort it [by time](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/400808/triplea?tab=reputation&sort=time) you get this:

[image: reputation tab]

Either way, you see upvotes and downvotes separately.

After you gain 1000 reputation votes, you can also view [upvotes and downvotes by clicking on the arrow showing question score](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user).